# In search of NT8 Historical Data for NQ

Tags: database, file, stock, back-testing

Hi Coders and Backtesters, i've finished coding a strategy but i have only 1 year worth of historical tick data, do you know where i could get access to the last 4-5 years?

Platform: NinjaTrader 8

Data Needed: Historical data for NQ - tick precision (not minute / day )

Data Range: Before July 2022, if you could provide even 1 month that would be great!

Where to find files on your PC: NT8 Folder / db / tick / NQ - XX-XX quarter, inside you should have .Last.ncd files.

Plan: if i can get access to a lot of data i would like to upload it and make it accessable for everyone free of cost, we could all benefits from a database of data!

Optional: if you have market data that could be useful too for accurate playback, so share it anyway!

Can't Download tick data from ninjatrader 8 for periods of over 1 year